# What logging can be used to log in GWT shared code?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, slf4j

There are three types of code in a GWT project:

1. Client code (GWT client / javascript)
2. Server code (servlet container / java)
3. Shared code (GWT client & servlet container / javascript & java)

Logging framework usable for each type:

1. Client - [gwt-log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/)
2. Server - [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/)
3. Shared - ???

I'd like to have a write once for the shared code that could include logging.

Any solutions out there for this?

Comment: Found this: http://code.google.com/p/xydra/wiki/XydraLog

Comment: Looks interesting. I wonder why they decided to use a different package name, though... What would be even more awesome: a project that emulates the slf4j API inside GWT, using the *same* package / class names. This would allow us to share the same code between the client and server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT 2.1 includes [java.util.logging emulation](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit-contributors/browse_thread/thread/e392ce6221430351/108070802fc44aad), you can find a [sample project](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/logexample) using it. You should be able to use this in shared code that's running on the client side and server side.

Comment: JUL -> SLF4J bridge is not very efficient. http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j So I'd prefer not to use it.

Comment: Yeah, JUL isn't the nicest solution out there, but that's what the GWT team is emulating in GWT 2.1. For something to log on both sides, I don't think you have many options. What code exactly are you going to be using this logging in? Usually the shared code is just domain objects (or DTOs).

Comment: JUL it may have to be... I haven't fully explored the use-case that my team needs for logging in the shared code. It's possible shared code doesn't _really_ need to log.

Comment: Here is the feature request: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4954 Also, Logback had a new feature that will help with performance: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#LevelChangePropagator